# Bibliography Management with bibtex memoir errors; undefined referenecs, replaced by a fixed 1

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to manage bibliography for my Bachelor's project using BibTex, but am running into several errors - I am using TexStudio as an editor, by the way.
My trial-code file "bibtrial.tex" (I cut away everything else in my file for clarity) is as follows;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric-comp,
sorting=ynt,
sortcites=true,
dashed=false,
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=3,
uniquelist=false,
uniquename=false,
doi=false,
url=false,
isbn=false,
eprint=false,
hyperref=true]{biblatex}
% Load the file with bibliographic information
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
    
Texttexttext \cite{Bravyikitaev}
    
\end{document}
```

with the bibliography.bib file looking like this;

```
@article{Bravyikitaev,
    title={The Bravyi-Kitaev transformation for quantum computation of electronic structure},
    volume={137},
    ISSN={1089-7690},
    url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4768229},
    DOI={10.1063/1.4768229},
    number={22},
    journal={The Journal of Chemical Physics},
    publisher={AIP Publishing},
    author={Seeley, Jacob T. and Richard, Martin J. and Love, Peter J.},
    year={2012},
    month={12},
    pages={224109}
}
```

However, when running the Trial code above, I get the following errors;

```
biblatex.sty Package keyval Error: dashed undefined. \blx@processoptions
bibtrial.tex There were undefined references.
bibtrial.tex Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) BibTrial(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
bibtrial.tex name{cite.0@Bravyikitaev} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

I then try to run Biber, by using Tools->Commands->Biber, and the process exits normally without errors.
Trying to recompile the bibtrial.tex file again, however, I am met with the exact same errors (as though running biber on the file does not work).
The output from running biber on my trial code is

```
Process started: biber.exe "BibTrial"

INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'BibTrial.blg'
INFO - Reading 'BibTrial.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'bibliography.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibliography.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'ynt/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'ynt' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'BibTrial.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to BibTrial.bbl

Process exited normally
```

Comment: This is not related to `memoir` as you get the same issue with `book`. Additionally you should load `hyperref` last (as it has to hook into stuff). The example then compiles if you outcomment the `dashed` option. And if included I get `Package keyval Error: dashed undefined.`. Looking at the code the styles `authortitle` and `authoryear` seems to support `dashed`  so I'm guessing not so for the style you're using.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work now. For posterity; I just had to out-comment the line "dashed=false"

Comment: @daleif Do you want to write up a quick answer here? §3.1.2.2 Style-specific [options] of the documentation confirms that styles of the `authoryear`/`authortitle` family have the `dashed` option, but not styles like `numeric` or `alphabetic`.